# SQL Server get outer table column into subquery join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to write a query that gets Income Statements for Investments and calculates how much each has made dependent on the time frame.

```
SELECT 
    iis.GrossIncome, dates.[Month], dates.[Year], s.TotalGrossIncome
FROM
    dbo.InvestmentIncomeStatements AS iis
JOIN 
    dbo.IssueDates AS dates ON iis.IssueDateID = dates.ID
JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         f.InvestmentID, SUM(f.GrossIncome) AS TotalGrossIncome
     FROM
         (SELECT 
              stment.InvestmentID, stment.GrossIncome, inment.[Name] as InvestmentName 
          FROM 
              dbo.InvestmentIncomeStatements stment
          JOIN 
              dbo.IssueDates AS dts ON stment.IssueDateID = dts.ID
          JOIN 
              dbo.Investments inment ON stment.InvestmentID = inment.ID
          WHERE 
              dts.[Month] + dts.[Year] < '???') AS f
    GROUP BY 
        f.InvestmentID, f.InvestmentName) AS s ON iis.InvestmentID = s.InvestmentID
```

In the place of the '???' I would like to write 'dates.[Year] + dates.[Month]'.
However I can't refer it. What should i do?

Comment: What do you mean you can't refer to them? That is called a correlated subquery and is valid syntax. Although I question Month + Year. That indicates something not well designed from a datatype standpoint.

Comment: 'The multi-part identifier  "dates.Year" could not be bound.' Is the error I get. Basically while I am inside that subquery I cant refer anything on the outside. Not like I can do in nested loops, for example. Obviously there is something I am not doing right...
Month + Year is a bit wierd, but it has purpose out of this context.

Comment: @SeanLange No, that's not a "correlated subquery". It's a "lateral subquery" and cannot use `JOIN` but should use `CROSS APPLY` (or `OUTER APPLY`) to be valid.

Comment: @TheImpaler thanks for the correction. :D

Comment: I agree with @SeanLange here, I'm actually very confused by the syntax `dts.[Month] + dts.[Year]`. What does `'March' + 2019` result in apart from a `varchar` cannot be convert to `int` error? Perhaps it's `3 + 2019` but that results in `2022`? Does look like a poor/odd design choice

Comment: @Larnu unless they are varchar and then it would be '32019' which is even more absurd.

Comment: Yes, Month is kept as a number. The reason for that is because the periods are months. If kept as DateTime the filtering by a period would be a lot harder (and slower). This is later useful in code as well.

Comment: but `dts.[Month] + dts.[Year] < '???'` is completely non-SARGable @RapGeneralofficial so that **will** be slow. Certainly you can store the date parts as well, as persisted computed columns, or by using a calendar table, but if both `[Month]` and `[Year]` are an `int` then, but that logic January 2018 is **before** December 2010 (`1 + 2018 = 2019`, `12+2010 = 2022`, `2019 < 2022`)

Comment: You are indeed right, seems I have to redo the dates. However I am more concerned my whole query is designed wrong, since I cant even get to the dates in the first place.

Comment: To fix the problem you're having, you need to change `JOIN (SELECT ...` to `CROSS APPLY (SELECT ...`, but that doesn't solve the problem of your design.

Comment: I would store the dates as a date datatype. And then if you need just the month to use as a period make that a computed and persisted column.